# How do I change my head title for different pages in Next.js's app directory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In the `app` folder of Next.js 13, I have a default rootlayout:

```
import "./globals.css";
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </head>
      <head />

      <body>
        <main>{children}</main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

And now I've created an account folder for the account page; I've created a `page.js` file there and also tried to create a `layout` file so that I can change the title; I saw a video on youtube where they change it like this code:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>account page</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </head>
      <head />

      <body>
        <main>{children}</main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

And it works for them, but when I try it myself it gives me an error:

```
1.validateDOMNesting(...): <html> cannot appear as a child of <main>.
2.You are mounting a new html component when a previous one has not first unmounted. It is an error to render more than one html component at a time and attributes and children of these components will likely fail in unpredictable ways. Please only render a single instance of <html> and if you need to mount a new one, ensure any previous ones have unmounted first.
```

Maybe I understand a little bit, I've already used the rootLayout I can't use the rootLayout again.

Comment: Why not just use Next's Head component: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head?

Comment: I'm using next.js 13 and it's seems like next.js 13 update this part with layout things

Comment: Hello NAYMUR! Can you let others know if your question is solved by interacting with the given answer?

Comment: I just skip using next.js 13, cause they said(next.js website) it's not properly ready for production build that's why I returning next.js12 and sorry about that I don't know is all these answer is correct or not. but what Yilmaz said, "it's not working"

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understood you are creating the second `RootLayout` inside the page folder. You have to remove the

```
<html lang="en">
  
</html>
```

Because rootLayout already has `html` element, and it renders `children` components. this `children` component is rendered inside the `body` element (you can confirm from chrome dev tools ). And now you are having `<body><html> </html></body>` structure

Answer (score 0):

In the `app` directory, the root `layout` wraps all nested ones, so as you did, you end up with two nested `<html>` with their `<body>` and everything,  and that's not correct.

Your nested `layout` should only return something that can go directly into the `{children}` part of the first one. To change the `<head>` of any page, even the root one, consider using [`head.js`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/head) file:

> The `head.js` special file allows you to configure the `<head>` tag for a route segment.

```js
// app/user/head.js

export default function Head() {
  return (
    <>
      <title>My User Page Title</title>
    </>
  );
}
```

As I told above, if you just create a project with Create Next App command, you would see in the root layout this code with the comment:

```js
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      {/*
        <head /> will contain the components returned by the nearest parent
        head.tsx. Find out more at https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/head
      */}
      <head />
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```